# Can I use the .Min() Linq extension method on a bool type?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find if I have any bools that are false in a collection. Can I use the following code to find it?

```
this.MyList.Min(e => e.MyBool)
```

I'm hoping this will return false if there is a false in the collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use (renamed the collection for reasons of readability):

```
bool anyFalse = myBools.Any(b => !b);
```

or

```
bool anyFalse = !myBools.All(b => b);
```

both are efficient since they *break* on the first `false`.

If there are complex objects in the collection(as it seerms to be) use:

```
bool anyFalse = MyList.Any(x => !x.MyBool);
```

or

```
bool anyFalse = !MyList.All(x => x.MyBool);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will work because `Boolean` is `IComparable<Boolean>` but it's *awkward* and thus it's **harder to understand the intent of your code**.

Additionally, your code will have to go through **the whole sequence** just to find out if there's a `false`, and it will throw if the sequence is empty.

Use [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) instead:

```
MyList.All(item => item.MyBool)
```

This will return `false` if there's any `false` value in the sequence. If the sequence is empty, `All` will return `true`.